# Using Oracle "Create User" command does not automatically create an associated schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm just getting started with Oracle data export and import and things worked perfectly fine the first time around. But then I came back next day repeated the exact same steps on the same systems, but get ORA-01435: user does not exist error.

**System Specs for all machines:**

-OS: Windows 2012 R2 x64

-Oracle Server: Oracle 11G Express x64

**Objective:**
I'm exporting data from Oracle server 1 and importing to Oracle server 2.

**Procedure:**
Export data dump is successful from Oracle server 1.

but when importing the data dump on Oracle server 2, I follow this procedure:

-Stop IIS service

`net stop WAS`

Create Schema/user account and Grant privileges before import

```
net stop WAS

sqlplus / as sysdba;

CREATE user PIE1 identified by PASS1;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO PIE1;

GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO PIE1;
```

According to oracle, all goes well, but look at the first image bellow. In DBeaver, I can see that only the User account PIE1 has been created, but NO schema.
[Oracle issue 1. User account created, but not the Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFmE2.png)

**Question 1:** According to Oracle, the command "Create User" IS supposed to also create an associated Schema. Anyone have an idea why this is no longer working for me? It worked once the night before.

I then continue the import procedure as follows:

```
imp PIE1/PASS1@xe file=c:\Backups\AVUSER2_6_7.dmp log=c:\Backups\import.log fromuser=AVUSER2_6_7 touser=PIE1;
```

But get the following error:
[Oracle claims the User doesn't exist even though it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqw0.png)

Oracle claims the User doesn't exist even though it does. I repeated the entire procedure and even created an identical import/export user account and credentials, and this error still comes up.

**Question 2:** Any idea why Oracle "Can't find" a user account that's clearly in the database?

Additional Info:

1. Checked that my windows account is in admin group
2. Checked that my windows account is in ORA_DBA group
3. Opened all CMD prompt as Admin

Comment: Is it possible that in DBeaver the Users folder was refreshed but the Schemas folder was not?  And maybe the import error is because of the `FROMUSER` and not the `TOUSER`; are you sure the dump file contains the user AVUSER2_6_7?

Comment: Hi Jon, I already refreshed the entire tree with the same results. I also noticed that even after manually creating the schema. after running the import, the schema gets removed.

Comment: Are you really using export data pump and regular import, or is that a typo?  I wouldn't think the two would be compatible.  Can you include the full export command you used?

Comment: The question says 'export data dump', not 'pump' - I misread that too at first *8-) As an aside, while I can understand you wanting to show the DBeaver GUI discrepancy in screenshots, it would be better to include the text of the command-line sessions rather than images of those - much easier to read, and they would be searchable, and some people can't get to the images at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you implied, users and schemas as the same in Oracle, you can't have a user without a schema. No idea about DBeaver, but as there are other users that aren't listed under 'schemas' (according to your second image - ANONYMOUS, DIP, ...) that seems to be unrelated.

(Purely a guess, but perhaps the user you're connect as in DBeaver just doesn't have visibility of any objects owned by those users - maybe it only lists users it can see in `all_objects`, say. Pure speculation, but you could investigate that by looking at the data dictionary while connect through SQL*Plus as the same user. [According to this old forum post](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=578&p=868&hilit=schemas+oracle#p868), there is an option to hide empty schemas...)

The import *is* connecting successfully as `PIE1` - you'd get a different error, ORA-01017, if it wasn't and you wouldn't see the 'Connected to...' banner or anything after that.

Your import command has a trailing semicolon that should not be there. The "importing ... objects into" message shows that it's trying to import into the `PIE1;` user and not the one you actually created, `PIE1`. Remove that semicolon and try again.

Incidentally, you can probably also remove the `@xe` TNS alias and stick to a local connection, assuming the environment is configured as it was whenyou ran SQL*Plus. You should also consider using datapump expdp/impdp rather than the legacy exp/imp.

Comment: Hi Alex, Sorry I'm away from my PC at this time. I think your suggestion about removing the extra semicolon after the touser name might work (Can't remember why i got so fixated on adding a semicolon to begin with). I'll try it once i get back to my computer and let you know. Thanks ahead for everyone's feedback so far...happy new year

Comment: It turns out I needed a vacation...smh there was an extra semicolon right after the touser name as Alex said. Thx for catching that...I must've updated my documentation with the wrong command and neglected to check the actual formatting.